# Histogram Equalization implementation using openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing my own implementation of histogram equalization, but it produces some *creepy* looking images. 
I got the color intensity of every pixel, then I got the probability by dividing the color intensity by the number of pixels in the picture. Then, I made a cumulative probability array that I later multiplied by 255 and floored it. This value ended up being the new color. What am I missing?

Before equalization
[image]

After equalization
[image]

My code:

```
void pixelFrequency(Mat img, int intensity[])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
            intensity[int(img.at<uchar>(j, i))]++;
}
void pixelProbability(Mat img, double probability[], int intensity[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        probability[i] = intensity[i] / double(img.rows * img.cols);
}
void cumuProbability(double probability[], double cumulativeProbability[])
{
    cumulativeProbability[0] = probability[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
        cumulativeProbability[i] = probability[i] + cumulativeProbability[i - 1];
}
void histogramEqualization(Mat& img, int intensity[], double probability[], double cumulativeProbability[])
{
    pixelFrequency(img, intensity);
    pixelProbability(img, probability, intensity);
    cumuProbability(probability, cumulativeProbability);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        cumulativeProbability[i] = floor(cumulativeProbability[i] * 255);
    for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
        {
            //int color = cumulativeProbability[int(img.at<uchar>(i, j))];
            img.at<uchar>(j, i) = cumulativeProbability[int(img.at<uchar>(i, j))];
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int intensity[256] = { 0 };
    double probability[256] = { 0 };
    double cumulativeProbability[256] = { 0 };
    Mat img = imread("ex.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    histogramEqualization(img, intensity, probability, cumulativeProbability);
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: seems like at some point you confuse `x` with `y`

Comment: yep. `img.at<uchar>(j,i) = cumu...(i,j))];`

Comment: @tobi303 dear God, I spent hours trying to look for the mistake. *cries* thank youuuuu

Comment: Working with a rectangular image would have revealed the problem much earlier, by a crash. Square images are good at hiding the width/height and x/y confusions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust not to mention square images on platforms with different byte ordering. Don't only test with image sizes <256. That once cost me a lot of debugging!